# Why do we study Lipschitz continuity condition? (As it is a special case of Holder continuity)

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Lipschitz continuity condition is a special case of Holder continuity condition. Then why to study Lipschitz condition? Is there any special importance of this condition?

Comment: Yes, you need Lipschitz continuity to get unique solutions to ODE, for example. Holder does not suffice. Lipschitz continuous functions are also exactly those whose generalized derivatives are essentially bounded.